# C# Function for splitting date range when value not found on a specific day

Tags: c#, date, range

I have a List with a date range as strings (for example '2019-05-01','2019-05-02','2019-05-05'...), and an array of the same length containing Boolean values.

I need to check each day in the date range against it's corresponding value in the Boolean area, and for any day where the value is FALSE, remove the date from the date range and split it into two ranges on either side of the value not found.

I have looked for algorithms that fit this pattern, but have not found any that will split a date range when a day is removed.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> ranges = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

List<string> dt_range = new List<string>() { "2019-05-01", "2019-05-02", "2019-05-03", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-05", "2019-05-06" };
var valid = new bool[dt_range.Count];
valid[0] = true;
valid[1] = true;
valid[2] = false;
valid[3] = false;
valid[4] = true;
valid[5] = true;

for(var i = 0; i < dt_range; i++)
{
    if(valid[i] == true)
    {
        // Continue checking days
    }
    else if (valid[i] == false)
    { 
        // remove this day from date range, and create 
        // date range prior and following this, while
        // continuing to check for the rest of the days
    }
 }
```

So if for 2019-05-03 the value was FALSE, then the range would be broken up into (2019-05-01,2019-05-02) and (2019-05-04,2019-05-05,2019,05-06), and would keep checking the second range, breaking up if need be. The first range (2019-05-01,2019-05-02) would be added to the ranges List>, while the second range would need to continue to be validated before being added to ranges list.

I am having a mental block solving this issue, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you expect the output to be

Comment: Are these new ranges valid or not?

Comment: Create a new list, rather than modify the existing.  Just add the ones where they're considered valid.

Comment: I recommend never having dates as strings in your code.  They should be `DateTime` and you can format them to strings for display or when serializing to a file.  And parse them when reading user input or de-serializing from a file.

Comment: Output would be a list that contains the valid ranges.  Fixed dt_range length per Austin's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only one loop it would be

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> ranges = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
string str1 = null;
string str2 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < dt_range.Count; i++)
{
    if (valid[i])
    {
        if (str1 == null)
        {
            str1 = dt_range[i];
        }
        str2 = dt_range[i];
    }
    else
    {
        if (str1 != null)
        {
            ranges.Add(Tuple.Create(str1, str2));
        }
        str1 = null;
    }
}
if (str1 != null)
{
    ranges.Add(Tuple.Create(str1, str2));
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding on the requirement is correct then below code can solve your first level of problem.

```
 List<string> dt_range = new List<string>() { "2019-05-01", "2019-05-02", "2019-05-03", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-05", "2019-05-06" };

        var valid = new bool[dt_range.Count];
        valid[0] = true;
        valid[1] = true;
        valid[2] = false;
        valid[3] = false;
        valid[4] = true;
        valid[5] = true;

        List<List<string>> FinalRange = new List<List<string>>();

        for (var i = 0; i <= valid.Length-1; i++) {

            List<string> Splitted_Date_Range = new List<string>();
            if (!valid[i]) {
                for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) {
                    Splitted_Date_Range.Add(dt_range[j]);
                }
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= valid.Length - 1; j++) {
                    Splitted_Date_Range.Add(dt_range[j]);
                }
            }

            if (Splitted_Date_Range.Count > 0) {
                FinalRange.Add(Splitted_Date_Range);
            }
        }
```

The loop i have written is for core level implementation sample , this can be used for further level of date splitting.

Comment: Thank you for the comments on the variable names, i will improve it next time on wards

Comment: Lol. Thanks. Just a little sarcasm for something that gets me a little wondering why people do it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @juharr that there would be a better data structure to solve your problem and I also highly recommend using `DateTime` to store dates, not `string`. However, using the example you provided, there is a solution below. Basically you keep a marker at the last valid element (which I called `previous`) and then update this when you hit an invalid element.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> ranges = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

List<string> dt_range = new List<string>() { "2019-05-01", "2019-05-02", "2019-05-03", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-05", "2019-05-06" };
var valid = new bool[dt_range.Count];
valid[0] = true;
valid[1] = true;
valid[2] = false;
valid[3] = false;
valid[4] = true;
valid[5] = true;

string previous = dt_range.First();
for (int i = 0; i < dt_range.Count; i++) {
    if (!valid[i]) {
        if (previous != dt_range[i]) {
            ranges.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(previous, dt_range[i - 1]));
        }
        previous = dt_range[i + 1];
    }
}

// capture last range
ranges.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(previous, dt_range.Last()));
```

The output I get from this is two ranges which I believe matches your desired output.

> (2019-05-01, 2019-05-02)
>
> (2019-05-05, 2019-05-06)

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my hat into the ring, and assuming you don't want blank ranges, but do want any remainder, I think it should look something like this:

```
         var ranges = new List<List<string>>();

         var dt_range = new List<string> {"2019-05-01","2019-05-02","2019-05-03","2019-05-04","2019-05-05","2019-05-06"};
         var validDates = new[] {true, true, false, false, true, true};

         int i = 0;
         int startPos = 0;
         foreach (var valid in validDates)
         {
            if (!valid)
            {
               if ((i-startPos) > 0 )
                  ranges.Add(dt_range.Skip(startPos).Take(i - startPos).ToList());
               startPos = i + 1;
            }

            i++;
         }
         // Handle any remaining dates
         if (startPos < i)
            ranges.Add(dt_range.Skip(startPos).Take(i - startPos).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this a little differently, Linq:

```
var groupedRange = dtRange.GroupBy(g => valid[dtRange.IndexOf(g)] );
```

Or for a full example:

```
List<string> dtRange = new List<string>() {"2019-05-01","2019-05-02","2019-05-03","2019-05-04","2019-05-05","2019-05-06"};
    var valid = new bool[dtRange.Count];
    valid[0] = true;
    valid[1] = true;
    valid[2] = false;
    valid[3] = false;
    valid[4] = true;
    valid[5] = true;

    var groupedRange = dtRange.GroupBy(g => valid[dtRange.IndexOf(g)] );

    foreach(var gr in groupedRange)
    {
       foreach(var row in gr)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(gr.Key + " " + row);
       }
    }
```

You end up with a new object with both lists.

The output would be:

```
True 2019-05-01
True 2019-05-02
True 2019-05-05
True 2019-05-06
False 2019-05-03
False 2019-05-04
```